# 拡散確率モデル画像合成手法の数学記号を教えてください。

Tags: python, 機械学習, tensorflow, 画像, pytorch

ディープラーニングの画像生成で使われる拡散確率モデルは、次のサイトで解説されています。

[論文]Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models
https://qiita.com/ground0state/items/565de257807b12dba52a

そのサイトのしょっぱなの次の式が説明できる方教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

特に、いきなり出てくる x0:T や dx1:T とはどういう意味でしょうか。

よろしくおねがいします。